# How to properly configure multicast message redistribution around the Artemis cluster

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using Artemis 2.8.0.

I've started two standalone servers in symmetric cluster mode and deployed address with type 'multicast' on both of them also I've created couple of predefined queues attached to this address. When I wrote messages to address on first server it successfully wroted to all queues attached to address. After that I connected to second server and created consummer for one of a queues and messages from first server didn't redistribute to second.

**I can't realize is it expected behaviour or not ?**

I had tried connect consummer by FQQN too but result was the same.
In documentation there isn't any special information about 'multicast' redistribution.

my broker.xml looks like

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>server1</name>
      <cluster-user>artemis</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>artemis</cluster-password>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      <journal-buffer-timeout>20000</journal-buffer-timeout>
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61716?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
         <acceptor name="cluster-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61717</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
         <connector name="cluster-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
      </connectors>
       <cluster-connections>
          <cluster-connection name="k24-artemis-cluster">
            <address></address>
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <check-period>5000</check-period>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <static-connectors>
              <connector-ref>cluster-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
          </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <address-setting match="k24.#">
            <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
            <max-delivery-attempts>100</max-delivery-attempts>
            <redelivery-delay-multiplier>1.5</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
            <redelivery-delay>5000</redelivery-delay>
            <max-redelivery-delay>50000</max-redelivery-delay>
            <send-to-dla-on-no-route>true</send-to-dla-on-no-route>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>
            <default-purge-on-no-consumers>false</default-purge-on-no-consumers>
            <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes><!--100 Mb-->
            <page-size-bytes>20971520</page-size-bytes><!--20 Mb-->
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
          </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
        <address name="k24.payment">
          <multicast>
            <queue name="k24.payment.bossbi">
              <durable>true</durable>
            </queue>
             <queue name="k24.payment.other">
              <durable>true</durable>
            </queue>
          </multicast>
        </address>
      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

startup logs on the first server

```
2019-05-23 11:12:33,188 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address k24.payment supporting [MULTICAST]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,188 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying MULTICAST queue k24.payment.bossbi on address k24.payment
2019-05-23 11:12:33,188 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying MULTICAST queue k24.payment.other on address k24.payment
2019-05-23 11:12:33,366 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601019: User anonymous is getting mbean info on target resource: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.AcceptorControlImpl@1b45c0e []
2019-05-23 11:12:33,373 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601019: User anonymous is getting mbean info on target resource: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.AcceptorControlImpl@73a8da0f []
2019-05-23 11:12:33,391 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,400 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61617 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,HORNETQ,STOMP,OPENWIRE]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,403 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2019-05-23 11:12:33,403 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.8.0 [server0, nodeID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,432 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601267: User anonymous is creating a core session on target resource ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366 [with parameters: [229b6b91-7d2a-11e9-94a2-106530a6cae3, artemis, ****, 102400, RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=3ded146a, clientID=null, nodeID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, transportConnection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyServerConnection@3e514577[ID=3ded146a, local= /127.0.0.1:61616, remote=/127.0.0.1:52806]], true, true, true, false, null, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.CoreSessionCallback@39407896, true, OperationContextImpl [1688453060] [minimalStore=9223372036854775807, storeLineUp=0, stored=0, minimalReplicated=9223372036854775807, replicationLineUp=0, replicated=0, paged=0, minimalPage=9223372036854775807, pageLineUp=0, errorCode=-1, errorMessage=null, executorsPending=0, executor=OrderedExecutor(tasks=[])], {}]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,461 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601267: User anonymous is creating a core session on target resource ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366 [with parameters: [22a110e2-7d2a-11e9-94a2-106530a6cae3, artemis, ****, 102400, RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=3ded146a, clientID=null, nodeID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, transportConnection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyServerConnection@3e514577[ID=3ded146a, local= /127.0.0.1:61616, remote=/127.0.0.1:52806]], true, true, true, false, null, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.CoreSessionCallback@200d654a, true, OperationContextImpl [964255832] [minimalStore=9223372036854775807, storeLineUp=0, stored=0, minimalReplicated=9223372036854775807, replicationLineUp=0, replicated=0, paged=0, minimalPage=9223372036854775807, pageLineUp=0, errorCode=-1, errorMessage=null, executorsPending=0, executor=OrderedExecutor(tasks=[])], {}]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,470 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601065: User artemis is creating a queue on target resource: ServerSessionImpl() [with parameters: [Address [name=activemq.notifications, id=0, routingTypes={MULTICAST}, autoCreated=false], notif.22a22253-7d2a-11e9-94a2-106530a6cae3.ActiveMQServerImpl_serverUUID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, _AMQ_Binding_Type<>2 AND _AMQ_NotifType IN ('SESSION_CREATED','BINDING_ADDED','BINDING_REMOVED','CONSUMER_CREATED','CONSUMER_CLOSED','PROPOSAL','PROPOSAL_RESPONSE','UNPROPOSAL') AND _AMQ_Distance<1 AND (((_AMQ_Address NOT LIKE '$.artemis.internal.sf.%') AND (_AMQ_Address NOT LIKE 'activemq.management%'))) AND (_AMQ_NotifType = 'SESSION_CREATED' OR (_AMQ_Address NOT LIKE 'activemq.notifications%')), true, false, -1, false, false, false, -1, null, false, null, false, 0, -1, false, 0, 0, false]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,494 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601019: User anonymous is getting mbean info on target resource: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.QueueControlImpl@28cb8c95 []
2019-05-23 11:12:33,507 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601265: User artemis is creating a core consumer on target resource ServerSessionImpl() [with parameters: [0, notif.22a22253-7d2a-11e9-94a2-106530a6cae3.ActiveMQServerImpl_serverUUID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, null, 0, false, true, null]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,542 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@9fe7fc4 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.k24-artemis-cluster.d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.k24-artemis-cluster.d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366], temp=false]@66c0982c targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@9fe7fc4 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.k24-artemis-cluster.d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.k24-artemis-cluster.d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366], temp=false]@66c0982c targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1676605578[nodeUUID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61716&host=localhost, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
2019-05-23 11:12:33,548 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.message] AMQ601500: User artemis is sending a core message on target resource: ServerSessionImpl() [with parameters: [TransactionImpl [xid=null, txID=378, xid=null, state=ACTIVE, createTime=1558595553462(Thu May 23 11:12:33 SAMT 2019), timeoutSeconds=300, nr operations = 0]@5c8669b1, CoreMessage[messageID=0,durable=false,userID=null,priority=4, timestamp=Thu May 23 11:12:33 SAMT 2019,expiration=0, durable=false, address=activemq.management,size=457,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_OperationName=sendQueueInfoToQueue,_AMQ_ResourceName=broker]]@1649442918, true, false, RoutingContextImpl(Address=null, routingType=null, PreviousAddress=null previousRoute:null, reusable=null, version=0)
..................................................
]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,552 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601263: User artemis is handling a management message on target resource 22a110e2-7d2a-11e9-94a2-106530a6cae3 [with parameters: [TransactionImpl [xid=null, txID=378, xid=null, state=ACTIVE, createTime=1558595553462(Thu May 23 11:12:33 SAMT 2019), timeoutSeconds=300, nr operations = 0]@5c8669b1, CoreMessage[messageID=385,durable=false,userID=null,priority=4, timestamp=Thu May 23 11:12:33 SAMT 2019,expiration=0, durable=false, address=activemq.management,size=457,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_OperationName=sendQueueInfoToQueue,_AMQ_ResourceName=broker]]@1649442918, true]]
```

And on the second

```
2019-05-23 11:12:27,556 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address k24.payment supporting [MULTICAST]
2019-05-23 11:12:27,557 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying MULTICAST queue k24.payment.bossbi on address k24.payment
2019-05-23 11:12:27,557 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying MULTICAST queue k24.payment.other on address k24.payment
2019-05-23 11:12:27,734 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601019: User anonymous is getting mbean info on target resource: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.AcceptorControlImpl@75d2da2d []
2019-05-23 11:12:27,736 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601019: User anonymous is getting mbean info on target resource: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.AcceptorControlImpl@3370f42 []
2019-05-23 11:12:27,753 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61716 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2019-05-23 11:12:27,762 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61717 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,HORNETQ,STOMP,OPENWIRE]
2019-05-23 11:12:27,766 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2019-05-23 11:12:27,766 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.8.0 [server1, nodeID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3]
2019-05-23 11:12:27,993 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2019-05-23 11:12:28,044 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2019-05-23 11:12:28,390 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2019-05-23 11:12:28,401 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2019-05-23 11:12:28,402 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to hawtio 1.5.5 : http://hawt.io/ : Don't cha wish your console was hawt like me? ;-)
2019-05-23 11:12:28,404 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.UploadManager] Using file upload directory: /home/dmitry/work/tools/apache-artemis-2.6.2/broker1/tmp/uploads
2019-05-23 11:12:28,414 INFO  [io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2019-05-23 11:12:28,441 INFO  [io.hawt.web.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/home/dmitry/work/tools/apache-artemis-2.6.2/broker1/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2019-05-23 11:12:28,461 INFO  [io.hawt.web.RBACMBeanInvoker] Using MBean [hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,rank=0,name=HawtioDummyJMXSecurity] for role based access control
2019-05-23 11:12:28,552 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ProxyWhitelist] Initial proxy whitelist: [localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.255.100.22, 10.255.100.32, bdk-laptop.lan.itecos.com]
2019-05-23 11:12:28,761 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://localhost:8261
2019-05-23 11:12:28,761 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:8261/console/jolokia
2019-05-23 11:12:28,762 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8261/console
2019-05-23 11:12:33,417 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601267: User anonymous is creating a core session on target resource ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3 [with parameters: [2298850f-7d2a-11e9-bf72-106530a6cae3, artemis, ****, 102400, RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=05d224cf, clientID=null, nodeID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, transportConnection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyServerConnection@27357d98[ID=05d224cf, local= /127.0.0.1:61716, remote=/127.0.0.1:57184]], true, true, true, false, null, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.CoreSessionCallback@1c98f1c2, true, OperationContextImpl [92544794] [minimalStore=9223372036854775807, storeLineUp=0, stored=0, minimalReplicated=9223372036854775807, replicationLineUp=0, replicated=0, paged=0, minimalPage=9223372036854775807, pageLineUp=0, errorCode=-1, errorMessage=null, executorsPending=0, executor=OrderedExecutor(tasks=[])], {}]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,450 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601267: User anonymous is creating a core session on target resource ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3 [with parameters: [229f89f0-7d2a-11e9-bf72-106530a6cae3, artemis, ****, 102400, RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=05d224cf, clientID=null, nodeID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, transportConnection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyServerConnection@27357d98[ID=05d224cf, local= /127.0.0.1:61716, remote=/127.0.0.1:57184]], true, true, true, false, null, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.CoreSessionCallback@6e34b6c6, true, OperationContextImpl [191090876] [minimalStore=9223372036854775807, storeLineUp=0, stored=0, minimalReplicated=9223372036854775807, replicationLineUp=0, replicated=0, paged=0, minimalPage=9223372036854775807, pageLineUp=0, errorCode=-1, errorMessage=null, executorsPending=0, executor=OrderedExecutor(tasks=[])], {}]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,489 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601065: User artemis is creating a queue on target resource: ServerSessionImpl() [with parameters: [Address [name=activemq.notifications, id=0, routingTypes={MULTICAST}, autoCreated=false], notif.22a4ba11-7d2a-11e9-bf72-106530a6cae3.ActiveMQServerImpl_serverUUID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, _AMQ_Binding_Type<>2 AND _AMQ_NotifType IN ('SESSION_CREATED','BINDING_ADDED','BINDING_REMOVED','CONSUMER_CREATED','CONSUMER_CLOSED','PROPOSAL','PROPOSAL_RESPONSE','UNPROPOSAL') AND _AMQ_Distance<1 AND (((_AMQ_Address NOT LIKE '$.artemis.internal.sf.%') AND (_AMQ_Address NOT LIKE 'activemq.management%'))) AND (_AMQ_NotifType = 'SESSION_CREATED' OR (_AMQ_Address NOT LIKE 'activemq.notifications%')), true, false, -1, false, false, false, -1, null, false, null, false, 0, -1, false, 0, 0, false]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,537 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601019: User anonymous is getting mbean info on target resource: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.QueueControlImpl@7865d90f []
2019-05-23 11:12:33,547 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601265: User artemis is creating a core consumer on target resource ServerSessionImpl() [with parameters: [0, notif.22a4ba11-7d2a-11e9-bf72-106530a6cae3.ActiveMQServerImpl_serverUUID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, null, 0, false, true, null]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,582 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@5c52e5b7 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.k24-artemis-cluster.d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.k24-artemis-cluster.d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3], temp=false]@3bb7d355 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@5c52e5b7 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.k24-artemis-cluster.d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.k24-artemis-cluster.d6998d86-7d25-11e9-88ce-7c76357cb366, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3], temp=false]@3bb7d355 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61716&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1052212904[nodeUUID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=localhost, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=d8938882-7d25-11e9-9b96-106530a6cae3])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61716&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
2019-05-23 11:12:33,589 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.message] AMQ601500: User artemis is sending a core message on target resource: ServerSessionImpl() [with parameters: [TransactionImpl [xid=null, txID=97, xid=null, state=ACTIVE, createTime=1558595553475(Thu May 23 11:12:33 SAMT 2019), timeoutSeconds=300, nr operations = 0]@d735c32, CoreMessage[messageID=0,durable=false,userID=null,priority=4, timestamp=Thu May 23 11:12:33 SAMT 2019,expiration=0, durable=false, address=activemq.management,size=457,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_OperationName=sendQueueInfoToQueue,_AMQ_ResourceName=broker]]@24312193, true, false, RoutingContextImpl(Address=null, routingType=null, PreviousAddress=null previousRoute:null, reusable=null, version=0)
..................................................
]]
2019-05-23 11:12:33,592 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.audit.base] AMQ601263: User artemis is handling a management message on target resource 229f89f0-7d2a-11e9-bf72-106530a6cae3 [with parameters: [TransactionImpl [xid=null, txID=97, xid=null, state=ACTIVE, createTime=1558595553475(Thu May 23 11:12:33 SAMT 2019), timeoutSeconds=300, nr operations = 0]@d735c32, CoreMessage[messageID=104,durable=false,userID=null,priority=4, timestamp=Thu May 23 11:12:33 SAMT 2019,expiration=0, durable=false, address=activemq.management,size=457,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_OperationName=sendQueueInfoToQueue,_AMQ_ResourceName=broker]]@24312193, true]]
```

My client code is written on scala. However I think it should be clear.

```
import java.util

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.TransportConfiguration
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.loadbalance.RoundRobinConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client._
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.{NettyConnectorFactory, TransportConstants}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.testng.Assert
import org.testng.annotations.Test

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class MulticastClusterMsgRedistributionTest {

  private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  private val ADDRESS_NAME = "k24.payment"
  private val QUEUE_NAME1 = "k24.payment.bossbi"
  private val QUEUE_NAME2 = "k24.payment.other"

  @Test
  def write(): Unit = {
    val sessionFactory = createSessionFactory(61616)
    val session = sessionFactory.createSession(false, false, false)
    val producer = session.createProducer(ADDRESS_NAME)
    session.start()
    1.to(50).foreach{ i =>
      val msg = session.createMessage(true)
      msg.writeBodyBufferString(s"msg $i")
      producer.send(msg)
      session.commit()
    }
    session.close()
    sessionFactory.close()

  }

  @Test
  def read(): Unit = {
    val sessionFactory = createSessionFactory(61716)
    val session = sessionFactory.createSession(false, false, false)
    val consumer = session.createConsumer(s"$ADDRESS_NAME::$QUEUE_NAME1")
    session.start()
    1.to(50).foreach{ i =>
      val msg = consumer.receive(2000)
      Assert.assertNotNull(msg)
      val body = msg.getBodyBuffer.readString()
      Assert.assertEquals(body, s"msg $i")
      log.info(s"-> $body")
      msg.acknowledge()
      session.commit()
    }
  }

  private def createSessionFactory(targetServerPort: Int): ClientSessionFactory = {
    val server = transportConfiguration(targetServerPort)
    val loc = ActiveMQClient.createServerLocatorWithHA(Seq(server): _*)
    loc.setUseTopologyForLoadBalancing(true)
    loc.setConnectionLoadBalancingPolicyClassName(classOf[RoundRobinConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy].getName)
    loc.addClusterTopologyListener(topologyListener(loc))

    val sessionFactory = loc.createSessionFactory()
    log.info(s"Session factory attached to ${sessionFactory.getConnection.getRemoteAddress}")
    sessionFactory
  }

  private def transportConfiguration(port: Integer): TransportConfiguration = {
    val srvParams  = new util.HashMap[String, Object]()
    srvParams.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "localhost")
    srvParams.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, port)
    new TransportConfiguration(classOf[NettyConnectorFactory].getName, srvParams, s"srv_localhost_$port")
  }

  private def topologyListener(loc: ServerLocator) = {
    new ClusterTopologyListener {
      override def nodeUP(m: TopologyMember, last: Boolean): Unit = {
        log.info(s"\t artemis member up = ${memberState(m)}")
        log.info(s"cluster state:\n ${loc.getTopology.getMembers.asScala.map(memberState).mkString("\n")}")
      }

      override def nodeDown(eventUID: Long, nodeID: String): Unit = {
        log.info(s"\t artemis member down = $nodeID")
        log.info(s"cluster state:\n ${loc.getTopology.getMembers.asScala.map(memberState).mkString("\n")}")
      }
    }
  }

  private def memberState(m: TopologyMember): String = {
    val live = Option(m.getLive)
    val backup = Option(m.getBackup)
    val backupState = backup.map{ b =>
      s"${b.getParams.get(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME)}:${b.getParams.get(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME)}"
    }
    val liveState = live.map{ l =>
      s"${l.getParams.get(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME)}:${l.getParams.get(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME)}"
    }
    s"$liveState backup to $backupState"
  }
}
```

I suppose Artemis should redistribute messages from all queues attached to multicast address from first server to second when there are consummers on second server.

Comment: Can you share the client code you used to connect to the FQQN on the node without the messages? Also, can you confirm from the logs that the nodes are clustering together successfully? You should see INFO level logging on both nodes about cluster bridges connecting to the other node.

Comment: @JustinBertram I have added servers logs and my client code into post